# Selecting a table element in Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I am getting started with Cucumber in Ruby on Rails and I would like to write a test that goes to a user index page and selects a certain row from a table and selects the edit link.  Are there any methods I can use to select a specific row or table element and then click the edit link?

Thanks!

John

Comment: What is contained within the table rows? If there isn't some easy way of identifying it through xpath, is there some text contained in a table cell you could look for?

Answer (score 2):

If you had a table in which you wanted to click the edit link in the 5th row, you could do something like this:

```
within all('table tr')[4] do
  click_link 'Edit'
end
```

However, if you edit link had a unique ID that would be a cleaner solution.

Comment: Where can I find documentation on these methods?  I am struggling with it a bit. . getting a 'can't convert nil into String' error.

Comment: Cool, thanks!  I haven't been using Capybara but I'm checking it out now.